# Ошибка в загрузке файла на сервер в yii2(move_uploaded_file)

Tags: php, yii2

Делаю как написано в [гайде](https://nix-tips.ru/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-input-file-upload.html#).

Смысл простой - загрузить файл на сервер. Код скопирован с сайта, только имена контроллера и view свои.

Выходит ошибка "PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException".
*move_uploaded_file(uploads/flower.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory*

In C:\OpenServer\domains\yii2-weblancer.ru\models\UploadForm.php at line 25 – yii\web\UploadedFile::saveAs('uploads/flower.png')

*$this->imageFile->saveAs('uploads/' . $this->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension);*

Папка uploads на сервере есть, файл png, что соответствует валидации. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Извините, я уже понял. У меня в настройках в open server стоит указание на папку web смотреть. Поэтому когда я указывал в коде uploads/, на самом деле он хотел сохранить в web/uploads, а вот там действительно нет такой папки и эта ошибка закономерна.